# Одинаковые последовательности в двух строках

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Таких вопросов не мало. Но все, что я нашел ищут либо конкретные куски в строках, либо просто совпадающие символы.
Вопрос такой. Есть заполненный строками List. В этом листе нужно найти общую для всех строк часть. НО! Нужно найти не все совпадающие символы, а именно первую совпадающую часть. 
Например:

```
QWERTY12345 YU
QWER TY4564 F
QWERGH145
QWER T777
QWE RBT
```

Результатом такого сравнения должно получится QWE.

Пробовал вот такой штукой.

```
public static string CommonString(string first, string second)
{
    return new string((first.Intersect(second)).ToArray());
}
```

Но она, похоже, ищет именно все встречающиеся символы и делает агрегейт, а значит не подходит.

Comment: А совпадать всегда с начала строк будет?

Comment: Да, в моем случае, совпадать будет с начала строк.

Comment: Если у меня есть пустая строка - то общих символов ноль? Если есть строка из 1 символа и он не совпадает с первым символом любой другой строки - то общих опять ноль?

Comment: В последовательности не будет пустых строк. Что до единичного символа - скорее всего, как минимум один символ будет совпадать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто сравнивать все первые символы, потом все вторые и т.д. пока не встретится хоть один не совпадающий...

Могу набросать на C/C++, C# - не моё...

На C++ что-то типа

```
string common(const vector<string>& sts)
{
    for(int i = 0;;++i)
        for(int j = 1; j < sts.size(); ++j)
            if (sts[j-1][i] != sts[j][i])
                return sts[0].substr(0,i);
}
```

*Update* С учетом высказанных в комментариях замечаний:

```
string common(const vector<string>& sts)
{
    if (sts.size() == 0) return "";
    if (sts.size() == 1) return sts[0];
    for(int i = 0;;++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < sts.size(); ++j)
            if (sts[j-1][i] != sts[j][i])
                return sts[0].substr(0,i);
        if (sts[0][i] == 0) return sts[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47700/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-----).

Answer (score 5):

Не претендую на ответ, просто немного переписал алгоритм @Harry на C#:

```
string Common(List<string> sts)
{
    if (sts.Count <= 1) throw new Exception("sts.Count <= 1");
    var result = "";
    for (int i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        var ok = true;
        for (int j = 1; j < sts.Count; ++j)
        {
            if (sts[j - 1][i] != sts[j][i])
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok == false)
        {
            result = sts[0].Substring(0, i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

p.s. обязательно обработайте исключения при вызове этого метода в пользовательском коде!

---

Немного подправил, не обошлось без Linq:

```
string Common(List<string> sts)
{
    sts = sts.Distinct().ToList();
    if (sts.Count == 0) throw new Exception("sts.Count == 0");
    if (sts.Count == 1) throw new Exception("sts.Count == 1");
    for (int i = 0;;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < sts.Count; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sts[j - 1][i] != sts[j][i])
                    return sts[0].Substring(0, i);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { return sts[0].Substring(0, i); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Третий вариант:

```
string Common(string[] buffer)
{
    var bufferLen = buffer.Length;
    if (bufferLen == 0) throw new Exception("buffer.Length == 0");
    if (bufferLen == 1) throw new Exception("buffer.Length == 1");
    var minStrLen = buffer.Min().Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < minStrLen; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < bufferLen; j++)
    {
        var str1 = buffer[j - 1];
        var str2 = buffer[j];
        if (str1.Length > i && str2.Length > i)
        {
            if (str1[i] != str2[i]) return buffer[0].Substring(0, i);
        }
        else
        {
            return buffer[0];
        }
    }
    return buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: мне кажется *одна из ветвей не возвращает значения*

Comment: @4per, спасибо, чуть подправил. Странно что студия не выдала ошибку.

Comment: А за что исключение на одну строку? Надо её и вернуть. И ещё, нерационально проверять это в цикле - длина списка не должна меняться во время работы алгоритма (а если меняется, то надо того, кто так многопоточный код написал, помучить).

Comment: @Qwertiy, а если там 0 строк? Нет, можно конечно проверить, но лучше бросить эксепшн девелоперу что что-то не то с входным списком. Условие перенес.

Comment: Про 0 согласен. Но 1 - это же вполне корректно?

Comment: Хм.. А на строках `{"a", "ab"}` оно не падает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, упадет, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: catch медленный...

Comment: @Qwertiy, как Вам третий вариант? Конечно плохо что дело имеем со строками, с типами значений было бы и проще и быстрее. Если что - правьте прямо в ответе...

Comment: maxStrLen - зачем нам max, если нужен min?

Comment: @Qwertiy, fixed. Только что увидел Ваш коммент выше по этому поводу.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так же хотелось бы увидеть Ваш вариант на шарпе, если есть под рукой.

Comment: Ещё ошибка во втором варианте: `sts = sts.Distinct().ToList(); ... if (sts.Count == 1) throw new Exception("sts.Count == 1");` - если все строки одинаковы, то будет исключение, что только одна строка дана. Свой вариант написал - смотри :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, по поводу исключения во втором варианте я знал. Когда он передает пустой массив или дубли - чтобы четко знал что что-то не так с параметром, именно поэтому сделал исключения и удаление дублей. Хотя это и не логично с моей стороны )

Comment: `if (str1.Length > i && str2.Length > i)` это же лишнее, т. к. `i < minLen`?

Answer (score 4):

http://ideone.com/KgDyXk

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    static string Common(List<string> strs)
    {
        if (strs == null || strs.Count == 0)
            return "";

        if (strs.Count == 1)
            return strs[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < strs[0].Length; ++i)
            for (int q = 1; q < strs.Count; ++q)
                if (strs[q].Length == i)
                    return strs[q];
                else if (strs[q][i] != strs[q-1][i])
                    return strs[q].Substring(0, i);

        return strs[0];
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>()), "");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "a" }), "a");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "a", "a" }), "a");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "a", "ab" }), "a");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "ab", "a" }), "a");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "ab", "cd" }), "");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "ab", "cd", "" }), "");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "ab", "ab" }), "ab");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "ab", "ab", "" }), "");
        Console.WriteLine("{1}: {0}", Common(new List<string>() { "abacaba", "aba", "abacaba" }), "aba");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение не претендует на звание оптимального, но зато совсем не громоздкое, плюс всегда приятно свести решение задачи к одному LINQ запросу :)

```
public static string FindCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    if (strings == null || !strings.Any())
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var prefix = strings
        .Aggregate((IEnumerable<char> string1, IEnumerable<char> string2) =>
            string1.Zip(string2, (letter1, letter2) => new
            {
                Letter1 = letter1,
                Letter2 = letter2
            })
            .TakeWhile(pair => pair.Letter1 == pair.Letter2)
            .Select(pair => pair.Letter1));

    return string.Join(string.Empty, prefix);
}

...

var prefix = FindCommonPrefix(new List<string> {
    "QWERTY12345 YU",
    "QWER TY4564 F",
    "QWERGH145",
    "QWER T777",
    "QWE RBT",
});

Console.WriteLine(prefix);
```

---

Небольшое пояснение:

1. Приведение типа `string` к типу `IEnumerable<char>` осуществляется с целью обеспечения доступа к отдельным символам строки. В отличие от вызова метода `String.ToCharArray` копирования символов не происходит.
2. Метод `Enumerable.Aggregate` применяет к последовательности символов агрегатную функцию:

   - "QWERTY12345 YU", "QWER TY4564 F" → "QWER";
   - "QWER", "QWERGH145" → "QWER";
   - ...
   - "QWER", "QWE RBT" → "QWE".
3. Метод `Enumerable.Zip` объединяет символы с одинаковым индексом до тех пор, пока не будет достигнут конец одной из строк. В данном случае используется также метод `Enumerable.TakeWhile`, поэтому объединение происходит до тех пор, пока в одной из строк не закончатся символы либо не станет ложным условие равенства символов.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static string CommonString(string big, string small)
    {
      string result = string.Empty;

      if (small.Length > big.Length)
      {
        var temp = big;
        big = small;
        small = temp;
      }

      //var res = CommonString("Cisco CISCO3640ATest", "Not3640ANot");
      
      for (int i = 0; i < small.Length; i++)
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int curi = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < big.Length; j++)
        {
          var stillOk = big[j] == small[curi];
          if (stillOk)
          {
            sb.Append(small[curi]);
            curi++;
          }
          
          if (!stillOk || curi >= small.Length)
          {
            if (result.Length < sb.Length)
            {
              result = sb.ToString();
            }

            sb.Clear();
            curi = i;
          }
        }
      }
      
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: Совсем другую задачу решили.

Comment: Ну там у автора как раз с таким смыслом функция используется. И с таким прототипом. Другое дело, что конечную задачу этой функцией может и не стоит решать, но я искал именно такой прототип и наткнулся на эту страницу. Ну и пришлось самому написать.